# Changing selection lines in a mutiplexer

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, output

We have a 4*1 multiplexer. So it will have two selection lines, AB.

Now what if we built the same multiplexer but with BA as selection lines.

- Would the output change?
- If it did how would it?

Comment: Draw the diagram. There's a schematic editor button on the edit toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. Click Save and Insert when done. Or draw the truth table. Use the `{}` button to apply fixed formatting (fixed-width font).

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is. You know what a multiplexer does. You know the role that the selection inputs have. You can trivially write down what happens if you swap them, and you seem to know that's the way forward. So do it.

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: It's a part of a question...

Comment: @AbhishekSharma So then you are posting your homework. We have some unwritten code here. We don't do other people's homework, but we help them to do it if they are stuck. What's the difference? We don't waste our time writing down complete solutions on just the questions. We instead review student's tries to solve the questions on their own. Your post is missing your tries. So we can't help you at the moment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework without any signs of prior research.

Comment: I had an exam coming up. That's why I asked this question in such a hurry. Me and my friends discussed it and we were able to get to a conclusion and understanding of concept.

Comment: And I didn't tell you to do my homework. I just asked a question that I randomly encountered in a book and I did search about it, infact I did try it myself and I was correct. I just wanted to make sure that my concept was right.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The labeling of signals is to a large extent arbitrary, though some standards have evolved over the years.  The function of a pin on an IC does not change just because you decide to rename it.  Hence the two select inputs on your 4:1 mux could be called (A,B), (B,A), (SEL1, SEL2), (Mutt, Jeff), or whatever you want.  You just have make sure you use the proper name when describing the function of the part, as would be be done with t truth table for your 4:1 mux.

Answer (score 0):

*Table 1. An AB 4 × 1 multiplexer.*

```
A  B    0  1  2  3
----    ----------
0  0    1  0  0  0
1  0    0  1  0  0
0  1    0  0  1  0
1  1    0  0  0  1
```

*Table 2. An BA 4 × 1 multiplexer.*

```
B  A    0  1  2  3
----    ----------
0  0    1  0  0  0
1  0    0  1  0  0
0  1    0  0  1  0
1  1    0  0  0  1
```

There's no difference. You've just changed the names.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. We didn't just swap A and B, their bits are, too.

Comment: Abishek, it's the same table. I'm sure you can swap the two first columns yourself. It's not clear what else you'd be asking here.

Comment: @Abishek, then what **are** you talking about? We've asked for clarification in your question but you haven't done it. Why not?